# Why does Linux use this "pointer to pointer" for list?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

```
#define TAILQ_ENTRY(type)                       \
struct {                                \
    struct type *tqe_next;  /* next element */          \
    struct type **tqe_prev; /* address of previous next element */  \
}
```

I find above code which uses **pointer to pointer**, and this is not the only one. I want to know why do so? Pointer itself cannot handle it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the point here is **deleting** elements. Consider that you have a [singly linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_list), which means that you are able to *forward* navigating throughout its nodes.

Now consider a generic list node (say `N_j`)  which you want to  delete. After deleting it you want to easily link the *previous node* (say `N_{j-1}`) to the *next* (say `N_{j+1}`). Thus, you need to modify the field `tqe_next` of the previous node `N_{j-1}` which requires a pointer to it, i.e. the *pointer to pointer* `tqe_prev` in `N_j`.

In other words, in *pseudo-code* terms, the following holds true

```
 *(N_j.tqe_prev) ==  (N_{j-1}).tqe_next
```

or

```
 N_j.tqe_prev ==  &(N_{j-1}).tqe_next
```

.

Comment: @Tom Xue, I further improved my answer. Please have a look.